# Nightly backup using Import XML Document arcpy ERROR 000791

Tags: arcpy, xml, data-backup

I'm having some trouble using arcpy.ImportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management to import an XML document into a file geodatabase for a nightly backup routine. The code for the import is as follows:

```
 try:
     arcpy.ImportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management(backUP, backUpGDB, "DATA","DEFAULTS")

 except Exception as error:
     print error
 else:
     fgdbFin = datetime.now()
     print "Finished backup process at: " + str(fgdbFin)
```

The error I'm getting reads: "ERROR 000791: Cannot access local or remote geodatabase."

Oddly, if I try running the Import XML Workspace Document tool in Catalog, it runs without an issue. I'm running the script from a virtual desktop which only has 4GB of memory and it does seem to tie up most of my memory when running though I'm not sure why it would throw this error and not crash due to lack of resources.

Has anyone experienced this and if so are there any workarounds or suggestions for getting this to run in Python?

Comment: If you remove your `try`/`except` statements for testing then you may be able to get a more informative error message.  In any event can you post a code snippet and the full error message from running that code snippet, please?